# always have issues with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to short out one issue with my htaccess.

```
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
   RewriteRule ^profile/(.*)$ details.php?profile=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
   RewriteRule ^industry/(.*)$ category.php?industry=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
   RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

it work fine as long as there is profile or industry match.. but now what i want to achieve is when above no rule matches then it should redirect user to home page (www.example.com). what is happening is it redirect me to index.php but the problem is on browser it still shows (www.example.com/skfjsf/sfjsfk) i want to change it to (www.example.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php [r=301,nc]      

//instead of 

RewriteRule ^index.php$ /index.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: thank you for answering PolCPP but unfortunetly when i type in browser  something like http://www.example.com/pfdsjfage/dgsd  it redirect to index.php but on browser window still it shows http://www.example.com/pfdsjfage/dgsd  i would like to display it something like http://www.example.com/index.php or http://www.example.com/

Comment: yes i got it...     RewriteRule . /index.php [R=301,L]  thank you

Comment: Ah, dang typos. No problem :) htaccess is annoying